# CSS Stylesheet so-language warning

Tags: html, css

I use Calibre (http://calibre-ebook.com/) to manage my ebooks, and it gives me a tool to edit both epub & azw3 formats as CSS & HTML documents.

When I run the Debugger, it gives me the following Errors & Warnings: (I've stripped most of the CSS file out)

```
@namespace h "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
.calibre2 {
  height: 422;  <!-- ERROR: CSS: Property: Invalid value for "CSS Level 2.1" 
                            property: 422 [91:5: height]    [stylesheet.css] -->
  width: 601;   <!-- ERROR: CSS: Property: Invalid value for "CSS Level 2.1" 
                            property: 601 [92:5: width]    [stylesheet.css] -->
}
.western {
  color: #000;
  direction: ltr;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  orphans: 2;
  so-language: en-GB;   <!-- WARNING: CSS: Property: Unknown Property name. 
                                      [109:5: so-language]    [stylesheet.css] -->
  text-align: center;
  widows: 2;
}
```

Frankly, I haven't spent much time on the Height & Width errors, thinking they may be related to my reading device (Samsung Note).

With the so-language error, I've tried changing it to `lang: en;` and `:lang en;`, both of which also error out.  I've tried googling "so-language", thinking it may have been deprecated & replaced, but I find very few pages that even contain it, & none that give any information on it.

Comment: Height and width require a unit to be specified. Like 10px or 10%. I have no clue what so-language is. might be a calibre thing? It might be that the so-language isn't a property in the css specification , but the software you are using, is using it but the debugger doesn't recognize it. Since its just a warning I would ignore it, because it doesn't sound like it is affecting your user experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [CSS 2.1 reference about `width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property):

> `Value:   <length> | <percentage> | auto | inherit`
>   [...]
>   `<length>`
>   Specifies the width of the content area using a length unit.

... and [length is defined as](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length):

> The format of a length value (denoted by `<length>` in this
>   specification) is a **`<number>` (with or without a decimal point)
>   immediately followed by a unit identifier** (e.g., px, em, etc.). After
>   a zero length, the unit identifier is optional.

In other words, you can only omit the unit if length is zero.

I've tested in a couple of browsers and they both fix the invalid width by assuming pixels, so it might be safe to add a `px` suffix; but it'd be better to find `class="calibre2"` in code and learn what that element is used for, so you can be sure you aren't breaking it.

As about `so-language`, I've been unable to find proper reference about it (only some code samples from ebooks) so I suspect it's a proprietary Amazon attribute. Calibre is probably using a standard third-party CSS validator so it's not aware of stuff that's not in the W3C recommendation. It's probably okay to ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only purpose of language tagging in CSS that I can find.

```
.western:lang(en-GB) { ... }
```

when an `html`-element has a `lang` attribute it will select this and style it.

example:
     `<span lang="en-GB">English</span>`

And indeed as @Vall3y said. `Position` and `dimension` attributes need `units`, like `px`, `%` or `em`.

However I'm not able to answer this question thoroughly because there is no real question in your post.

Comment: Apparently the invalid `so-language` property is something that the OpenOffice CSS generator adds in.  Obviously it isn't hurting anything, I'm simply a/r enough that such things bug me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The height and width errors you mentioned are in a calibre class that is applied to an image tag in your epub or azw3 source. Usually, an image tag will look something like this:

```
 <img src="foo.gif" height="422" width="601">
```

Note that you do not have to specify a "pixels" suffix like px for the height and width in an image tag because it is taken to be pixes by default, but you will find it has been rendered in your ebook as:

```
 <img src="foo.gif" class="calibre2">
```

and coupled with the CSS:

```
.calibre2 {
 height: "422";
 width: "601"
}
```

which is why the CSS parser is throwing an error. When the height and width properties are farmed out this way to the CSS they do throw a parsing error in calibre. This probably doesn't present a problem to eReaders and you can always move the height and width properties back into the epub/azw3 html files to get rid of the CSS parsing error, but the easiest way to get rid of the error messages would be to change the CSS class to:

```
.calibre2 {
  height: 422px;
  width: 601px;
}
```

because specifying px for an image tag, while not required, does no harm. As for the so-language property, just search-and-replace it with blank text using calibre's editor. That's what I do. But it will just be ignored by eReaders and should present no problems.